# Find the possible values of angle $A$ in which $BX\cdot AB=IB^2$, $CY\cdot AC=IC^2$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Triangle $ABC$ had incenter $I$. Let points $X,Y$ be located on the line segment $AB,AC$ respectively, so that $BX\cdot AB=IB^2, CY\cdot AC=IC^2$. Given that the points $X,I,Y$ lie on a straight line, find the possible values of the measure of angle $A$.

It is a peculiar type question. I can't answer any this type question. I think we can't do this problem using geometry. Somebody please help me. It is a INMO question.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you give a reference of the original text of this INMO question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It is just angle chasing. The condition $BX\cdot BA=BI^2$ tells you that the circumcircle of $AXI$ is tangent at $I$ to the $BI$-line. Similarly, the circumcircle of $AIY$ is tangent at $I$ to the $CI$-line. Consider the centres of these circles: they both have to lie on the perpendicular bisector of $IA$. Compute the angles in the resulting configuration and translate the collinearity of $X,I,Y$ in a trigonometric equation in $\widehat{A}$. Solve it and deduce
$$ \color{red}{\widehat{A}=60^\circ}.$$
This should help you in chasing angles:
[image]

Comment: #Jack D'Aurizio: Please tell me why the two green angled are 90 degree.I have problem on only this . Otherwise okay.

Comment: @SufaidSaleel: draw the circumcircle of $AXI$ and consider the two lines $BA$ and $BI$ emanating from $B$. Since $BX\cdot BA=BI^2$, it means that the $BI$ line is tangent at $I$ to the previous circle, hence the centre of such a circle lies on a line through $I$ that is perpendicular to $BI$.